# Append characters to a string in multiple rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to update a single column in multiple rows by appending the string '999':

```
UPDATE integration.ol_orders
SET order_id = ((SELECT order_id
             FROM   integration.ol_orders
             WHERE  status = 2) || '999')
WHERE status = 2
```

but for whatever reason, I keep getting the error of "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row tips".

So, as I iterate my n rows, I'm trying to do:

```
a1 = a1 || '999'
a2 = a2 || '999'
a3 = a3 || '999'
an = an || '999'
```

Any suggestions how to go about this?

edit: changed '+' to '||', still no luck

Comment: Execute your subquery (`SELECT order_id FROM   integration.ol_orders WHERE  status = 2`) and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: @mmmmmpie 14 rows are returned

Comment: Theres your problem. You are trying to set 1 row equal to the output of 14 rows + '999'. BTW `+` isn't how you concatenate in oracle its `||`.

Comment: @mmmmmpie how would I be able to adjust that "set 1 row equal to" to "set our sub-queries values to our updated values"?

Comment: I don't really understand the question but what you are trying is really well explained in @jpw's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subquery looks unnecessary, just doing this should work:

```
UPDATE integration.ol_orders 
SET order_id = order_id || '999' 
WHERE status = 2
```

If I remember right Oracle uses `||` for concatenation. It might be necessary to cast the `order_id` to a character type if it's an integer, I'm not sure about that and can't test it at the moment. (The conversion should be implicit as stated in a comment, otherwise you can use `TO_CHAR()` to cast it explicitly).

Make sure to have a backup or copy of the table before running though...

Comment: I agree, though it would be nice to confirm that order_id is not a number.  Certainly antihero989 does treat it that way in the attempt above.

Comment: Oracle will implicitly convert `order_id` to a varchar2 in order to apply the concatenation.

Comment: True, though I dislike depending on implicit casting.

Comment: @Allan Thanks, wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `CONCAT` function in `Oracle SQL` to tackle the issue and it seems cleaner.

```
UPDATE integration.ol_orders 
SET order_id = CONCAT (order_id,'999') 
WHERE status = 2;
```

Just for information:

There are two ways to concatenate Strings in `Oracle SQL`. Either using `CONCAT` function or `||` operator.

`CONCAT` function allows you to concatenate two strings together

```
SELECT CONCAT( string1, string2 ) FROM dual;
```

Since `CONCAT` function will only **allow you to concatenate two values together**. If you want to concatenate more values than two, you can n**est multiple CONCAT function** calls.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('A', 'B'),'C') FROM dual;
```

An alternative to using the `CONCAT` function would be to use the **||** operator

```
SELECT 'My Name' || 'My Age' FROM dual;
```